# PYTHON : Change the value of an integer variable without recreate a variable

Tags: python

I would like to know if there is a way to edit the value of an integer variable instead of create a new one to replace the previous. The code should look almost like that :

```
>>> myInt = 1

>>> print myInt

1

>>> myInt.setattr (2)

>>> print myInt

2
```

Comment: ints are immutable so you are always creating a new object, why would you not do `myInt = 2` ?

Comment: I do `myInt = 2` but there was sometimes where I would "edit" my variable instead of replace it. For example, if we could edit a variable, we could do it from a function. But we can' so I will do without ^^

Answer (score 2):

`myInt` counts as one variable. So actually:

```
myInt = 2
```

changes the value of the variable but not the variable itself.

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_%28computer_science%29)

> In computer programming, a variable or scalar is a storage location paired with an associated symbolic name (an identifier), which contains some known or unknown quantity or information referred to as a value.

So assigning is the operation needed to change the value of a variable.

Comment: To be specific, the "value" of a variable in Python is a reference to an object. The assignment `myInt = 2` changes the value of `myInt` from a reference to the object `1` to a reference to the object `2`.

Answer (score 1):

```
class FakeMutableInt(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.__val = val

    def setval(self, newval):
        self.__val = newval

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.__val + other

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return self.__val - other

    # etc
```

Of course this is all rather pointless, but it *will* allow you to do:

```
>>> myInt = FakeMutableInt(3)

>>> myInt.setval(5)
```

not that I'm sure why you'd ever want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

myInt is a variable which can be resigned a new value. When you use "=" in python, you are essentially telling Python to find the slot in memory which points to the variable "myInt" and set it to whatever follows after the "=". This is how most programmers change the value of a variable. Keep in mind that assignment will not create a new variable. Its just reassigns the value in that memory location.

Also, Python is different from other languages in the sense that you do not have to explicitly declare the data type. Whereas in C/C++ and Java, if you want to create a new variable of type int you would do the following:

int x = 6;

That would *declare* a variable of type int and *initialize* that variable to the value 6.

In Python this is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

`myInt` is a label. You can't change the label, just what it is hanging from. You can hang many labels onto an object:

```
a = 9
b = 9
c = 9
```

There is only one `9` object, and three labels, `a`, `b`, and `c`. You cannot change `9` and you cannot change `a`. You can change what `a` is hanging from:

```
a = 6
```